# How to extract and search for duplicated numbers within a string in python?

Tags: python

I am using itertools.combinations and intertools.product to combine some data into a dataframe. In order to preserve some numeric values ("FightNum"), i converted these numbers to a list and then to a string.

This results in data that looks like this within my dataframe row:
[image: sample data]

Ideally what I want to have happen is, I want extract the numbers from this row and check to see if any one of the 6 numbers is duplicated. Because of the structure of these rows (2 list of strings), I am unsure how to extract the numbers from this string to then check for duplicates within each cell?

For example, if a DataFrame cell has these values, I want to flag it as having duplicates:

```
["['1', '3', '4']", "['1', '3', '10']"]
```

This is because 1 and 3 both show up twice, rather than having 6 unique numbers in this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and sweet.

```
import re

text = """['1', '3', '4']", "['1', '3', '10']"""
nums = set(re.findall("\d+", text))
```

If `len(nums) < 6`, discard it. I assumed the numbers are represented consistently, i.e. `1` wouldn't appear both as `1` and `01`. If that's the case, you can easily create a set of integers instead of strings; I leave that to you as an exercise.

Comment: I implemented this one and it does exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

This code should return what you want

```
string_list = [['1', '3', '4'], ['1', '3', '10']]

numbers = {}
for list in string_list:
    for item in list:

        if item not in numbers:
            numbers[item] = 1
        else:
            numbers[item] += 1

print(numbers)
```

And this returns

```
{'1': 2, '3': 2, '4': 1, '10': 1}
```

Which means there are 2 ones, 2 threes, 1 number '4' and 1 number '10'. Therefore, there are duplicates.

If you don't want to know how many duplicates there are, you can just run:

```
string_list = [['1', '3', '4'], ['1', '3', '10']]

numbers = []
duplicates = False
for list in string_list:
    for item in list:

        if item not in numbers:
            numbers.append(item)
        else:
            duplicates = True
    if duplicates:
        break
    
print('There are duplicates' if duplicates else 'There are no duplicates')
```

This returns

```
There are duplicates
```

If you change the string_list to [['1', '3', '2'], ['5', '8', '10']] it returns

```
There are no duplicates
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I didnt end up using it due to a shorter solution but I appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import ast
from collections import Counter
import itertools
x=["['1', '3', '4']", "['1', '3', '10']"]

y=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([ast.literal_eval(m) for m in x]))
z=dict(Counter(y))
m=list(set(y))
print(z,m)
```

Prints

```
{'1': 2, '3': 2, '4': 1, '10': 1} ['3', '1', '4', '10']
```